# Required Microsoft RSAT dlls and exe files

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, batch

I've got to script some Active Directory actions (*remove computer object*) but will be limited to using a batch file; I'm tied to a product that is looking for a specific batch file.  I'll place my batch file on a Windows system; a service will call the batch file and perform its actions.

Since I need to use the dsrm command (from the RSAT tools that won't be on all my systems), I can use bitsadmin inside the script to pull the dsrm executable from a web server.  However, there must be some dlls that I need to pull as well because just getting dsrm.exe doesn't seem to be enough.  Does anyone know what files are needed to be able to use the dsrm command without installing the RSAT tools on a system?

Comment: i would suggest to use a debugger to find used/rew files

Comment: isnt it possible with native powershell commands? since you did not wrote an example so and hence my glassball is broken still a while ago youll need to feed us with more information